Vector approximation program malfunction
I created a program with a friend that should approximate a vector, the input data being some points from that vector. My friend wrote a line of code that i cannot understand, and it is malfunctioning:
model = make_pipeline(PolynomialFeatures(degree), RidgeCV(alphas=ridge_alpha,normalize=True,cv=5))

I tried executing this line of code, but it resulted in an error:
C:\Users\USER\OneDrive\Desktop\programming\python\vector approximation> & "c:/Users/USER/OneDrive/Desktop/programming/python/vector approximation/.venv/Scripts/python.exe" "c:/Users/USER/OneDrive/Desktop/programming/python/vector approximation/file.py"
50
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\USER\OneDrive\Desktop\programming\python\vector approximation\file.py", line 78, in <module>
    model = make_pipeline(PolynomialFeatures(degree), RidgeCV(alphas=ridge_alpha,normalize=True,cv=5))
                                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: _BaseRidgeCV.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'normalize'

How to solve this problem?

You may want to update your version of the relevant library (sklearn?)

RidgeCV does not accept argument normalize, check the documentation: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.RidgeCV.html

Try RidgeCV(alphas=ridge_alpha,cv=5)

normalize argument was deprecated. It is only avaliable in scikit-learn version 1.1.3 or lower. According to the documentation instead of normalize you need to: If you wish to standardize, please use StandardScaler before calling fit on an estimator with normalize=False.
